# jQuery menu doesn't close

Tags: jquery, css, animation, menu

I am new to jQuery and I have problems with closing menu animation. The burger menu when clicked on services, portfolio etc. the menu doesn't do the ending animation and just stays there. I can see it moving the page but that's it. 
The menu just doesn't do the closing animation as it should and stays on the screen while the page moved as desired. I have no idea what's happening

Here's the code:
https://codepen.io/sqerry/pen/mdJzGjd

```
  $('.menu-toggler').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('.bar.half').toggleClass('open');
  })
});
```

```
 <div class="menu-toggler">
      <div class="bar half start"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar half end"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="index2.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
.top-nav.open {
    top: 0;
    border-radius: initial;
}

.menu-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3rem;
    right: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: transform 650ms ease-out;
}



.menu-toggler.open {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffe838, #fd57bf);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: .8rem;
}

.bar.half {
    width: 50%;
}

.bar.start {
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.start {
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(.8rem);
}

.bar.end {
    align-self: flex-end;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.end {
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(-1rem);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, add `.nav-link` to listen click event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.menu-toggler, .nav-link').on('click', function () {
    $('.menu-toggler').toggleClass('open');
    $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('.bar.half').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you want the menu to close when you click on one of the menu links.  You currently don't have any triggers set up for that to happen.  You would need to bind the links to trigger on a "click" event.